# Yii actionError not handling request when error occurs

Tags: php, yii, yii-events

I have made my custom controller and set it as default in my main config file.

All the other actions are working fine. But when there is any error i have made :

```
 public function actionError() {
      echo 'Error'; die;
  }
```

and then i made a not found request. It did not did the action written by me, but did default action.

Please suggest!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use your custom error action, you have to configure the [`errorAction`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CErrorHandler#errorAction-detail) in the [`errorHandler`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CErrorHandler) application component. You can do so in your `main.php`. If your controller is `CustomController` you'd configure:

```
'components' => array(
    // ...
    'errorHandler' => array(
        'errorAction' => 'custom/error',
    ),
    // ...
```

Comment: CHttpException

The system is unable to find the requested action "error".

Comment: Sorry, you had to replace `site` with `custom` in my initial response. But you you probably already figured that out ;).

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to echo inside the controller.Create a view file inside your views folder and render it like so `public function actionError(){  $this->render('viewName') }`